# Why is Windows Defender Antimalware at sustained high network utilization?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-10, network-traffic

2016 Dell Precision 5510 laptop workstation
Windows 10 Pro v1607 Build 14393.222
Core i7-6820HQ
32GB RAM

---

This high-end workstation was taking 30 seconds to open a 1 page Word document from the network file server. Checking Task Manager, I found Windows Defender Antimalware Service was utilizing up to 32Mbps of the Wi-Fi connection. This continued for at least 30 minutes. Any idea why this would happen?

I'm 15 feet from the Wireless Access Point.

I understand Defender is not the ideal antivirus solution and has no central management, etc. And I understand virus/malware definitions are updated daily, but this network utilization seems extreme and abnormal for a default configuration.

Please offer suggestions for troubleshooting or explanations as to what might be happening rather than recommendations to disable it and replace it.

[image: Network Utilization]
[image: Wi-Fi Usage]